# Как исправить ошибку FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:?

Tags: python, discord.py, pillow

Файл находится в директории, открывается при помощи модуля PIL

Скрипт:

```
@bot.command(name = "a")
async def a(ctx, *, text):
    text1 = text
    if len(text1) >= 30:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, длина текста не должна превышать 30', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        return
    else:
        achievement = Image.open("ach.png") #открытие файла
        colors = ["white"]
        drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(achievement)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("F77 Minecraft.ttf", 15)
        for color in colors:
            drawer.text((60, 35), text = text1, font = font, fill = color)
        achievement.save("exit.png")
        file = discord.File("exit.png", filename = "exit.png")
        embed = discord.Embed(color = discord.Colour.gold())
        embed.set_image(url="attachment://exit.png")
        await ctx.send(file = file , embed = embed)
```

Полная развертка ошибки:

```
Ignoring exception in command a:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/timofeitarasenko/Desktop/bebrobot/bot.py", line 144, in a
    achievement = Image.open("ach.png")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3068, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ach.png'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ach.png'
```

Comment: В какой директории файл? Наверняка текущая директория у скрипта совсем не такая, как вы думаете. Сделайте `print(os.getcwd())` и посмотрите, какой у скрипта текущий каталог.

Comment: я уже исправил ошибку оказывается скрипт открывал при запуске другую директорию и не выходил из нее